# Chrome not updating styles when last-child changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

## Problem

Styles are not being updated when the `last-child` changes due to extra elements being added dynamically with JavaScript.

## Example

Click "Add more blocks" in the snippet below. When the new blocks are added the fourth `.block` element ("Test block 4") will not have a bottom red border even though it is no longer the last element in `#container`.

```js
$("#addMore").one("click", function() {
  $("#container").append($("#container").html());
  $(this).remove();
});
```

```css
.block {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  counter-increment: block;
  margin: 20px 0;
  position: relative;
}
.block:after {
  content: " " counter(block);
}
.block:last-child {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="block">Test block</div>
  <div class="block">Test block</div>
  <div class="block">Test block</div>
  <div class="block">Test block</div>
</div>
<div id="addMore">Add more blocks</div>
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cg8o2e2e/)

## Expected behaviour

After clicking "Add more blocks" all `.block` elements should have a bottom red border *except* the eighth block ("Test block 8").

## Browsers effected

Tested and not working in Chrome 55.0.2883.87 m. Expected behavior returned by IE 11.0.9600.18538 and Firefox 50.1.0.

---

Can this be resolved *without*:

- Using JavaScript (i.e. dynamically adding a class which removes the red border from the last element)?
- Restructuring the CSS to not use `last-child` (i.e. using `first-child` and `border-top` instead)?

Comment: You are facing [Margin Collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing) issue. Change `margin` to `padding` and you will see that styles are being applied.

Comment: @MuhammadUsman Thanks for the comment but this isn't due to margin collapsing https://jsfiddle.net/8zhoybo8/

Comment: Yes you are right. My apologies. Let me try to figure out why is it happening.

Comment: @MuhammadUsman . This will not be solved by changing margin to padding. Styles are not updated properly, This might be because of appending html directly. Try different solution than appending html directly.

Comment: @HiddenHobbes It seems like a bug in chrome browser.

Comment: I tried with `clone()` and still the same issue is there...

Comment: Yeah I think you're right @MuhammadUsman as it works as expected in IE and Firefox. Interested to know if anyone has come across a  fix otherwise I'll have to look into restructuring the CSS a bit.

Comment: FWIW, this could be a regression problem in Chrome. It works fine for me in Chrome Version 43.0.2357.81 m (that is, only the 8th element doesn't have a bottom border).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For what it's worth, as a workaround you could replace the `last-child` pseudo class with `nth-last-child(1)` which does exactly the same thing as last-child, but is unaffected by the bug.

```js
$("#addMore").one("click", function() {
  $("#container").append($("#container").html());
  $(this).remove();
});
```

```css
.block {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  counter-increment: block;
  margin: 20px 0;
  position: relative;
}
.block:after {
  content: " " counter(block);
}
.block:nth-last-child(1) {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="block">Test block</div>
  <div class="block">Test block</div>
  <div class="block">Test block</div>
  <div class="block">Test block</div>
</div>
<div id="addMore">Add more blocks</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Danield, this is exactly what I was after as it requires minimal modifications to get round a browser specific bug.

Answer (score 1):

I tested in Chrome 55.0.2883.87 and it baffles me - clearly a bug.

Even when I used [`.clone()`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) instead on `.html()` the issue is there:

```
$("#container").append($("#container > .block").clone());
```

A possible *fix* might be to *force* a *re-render* of `container` - I used this for the re-render:

```
$('#container').hide().show(0);
```

See demo below:

```js
$("#addMore").one("click", function() {
  $("#container").append($("#container > .block").clone());
  // fix: by forcing re-rendering
  $('#container').hide().show(0);
  $(this).remove();
});
```

```css
.block {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  counter-increment: block;
  margin: 20px 0;
  position: relative;
}
.block:after {
  content: " " counter(block);
}
.block:last-child {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="block">Test block</div>
  <div class="block">Test block</div>
  <div class="block">Test block</div>
  <div class="block">Test block</div>
</div>
<div id="addMore">Add more blocks</div>
```

Comment: Ah, good thinking! Think I'll go down this route as it does appear to be a bug and requires no changes to the valid CSS. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks kukkuz this is a good and viable solution however I slightly prefer @Danield's answer as it is CSS only and doesn't require additional script.

Comment: @HiddenHobbes sure :)

Answer (score 1):

Playing a little bit with this issue hints the presence of some bug in chrome browser.

However I've noticed that if we use `border-top` instead of `border-bottom` then it works correctly.

**CSS:**

```
.block:not(:first-child) {
  border-top: 1px solid red;
}
```

```js
$("#addMore").one("click", function() {
 $("#container").append($("#container").html());
 $(this).remove();
});
```

```css
.block {
  counter-increment: block; 
  padding: 20px 0;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}
.block:after {
  content: " " counter(block);
}
.block:not(:first-child) {
  border-top: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="block">Test block</div>
  <div class="block">Test block</div>
  <div class="block">Test block</div>
  <div class="block">Test block</div>
</div>
<div id="addMore">Add more blocks</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, you've confirmed what I was thinking and I'll likely fix my particular implementation in this manner. Going to leave the question open for a bit just in case there is a way to fix the issue while still using `last-child`.

Comment: Thanks again @MuhammadUsman although in the end I found the re-render route by kukkuz preferable as no changes were required to my CSS.

Comment: @HiddenHobbes sure, no problem at all :)

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced similar issues when adding rows dynamically into tables with a css style of `td:last-child` and border-right. It would work when the page first loaded but as soon as extra `<tr>` elements were added into the table both new and existing rows could sometimes render with no right border.

I replaced it with `td:last-of-type`, which seems to work fine.